# Why shortest path not always found for Leetcode 1129 challenge?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [1129. Shortest Path with Alternating Colors](https://leetcode.com/problems/shortest-path-with-alternating-colors/):

> You are given an integer `n`, the number of nodes in a directed graph where the nodes are labeled from `0` to `n - 1`. Each edge is red or blue in this graph, and there could be self-edges and parallel edges.
>
> You are given two arrays `redEdges` and `blueEdges` where:
>
> `redEdges[i] = [aᵢ, bᵢ]` indicates that there is a directed red edge from node `aᵢ` to node `bᵢ` in the graph, and
> `blueEdges[j] = [uⱼ, vⱼ]` indicates that there is a directed blue edge from node `uⱼ` to node `vⱼ` in the graph.
>
> Return an array `answer` of length `n`, where each `answer[x]` is the length of the shortest path from node `0` to node `x` such that the edge colors alternate along the path, or `-1` if such a path does not exist.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: n = 3, redEdges = [[0,1],[1,2]], blueEdges = []
> Output: [0,1,-1]
> ```

Here is my code for that problem:

```
class Solution:
    def shortestAlternatingPaths(self, n: int, redEdges: List[List[int]], blueEdges: List[List[int]]) -> List[int]:

        res = [0] + [-1]*(n-1)

        Red = defaultdict(list)
        Blue = defaultdict(list)

        for x,y in redEdges:
            if x!=0 or y!=0: 
                Red[x].append(y)

        for x,y in blueEdges:
            if x!=0 or y!=0:
                Blue[x].append(y)


        def dfs(vertex,color,cost):
        
            if color == "red":
                for x in Red[vertex]:
                    if res[x] != -1:
                        res[x] = min(cost,res[x])
                    else:
                        res[x] = cost

                    if vertex in Red.keys():
                        del Red[vertex]
                    dfs(x,"blue",cost+1)


            else:
                for x in Blue[vertex]:
                    if res[x] != -1:
                        res[x] = min(cost,res[x])
                    else:
                        res[x] = cost

                    if vertex in Blue.keys():
                        del Blue[vertex]
                    dfs(x,"red",cost+1)

        dfs(0,"red",1)
        dfs(0,"blue",1)

        return res
```

But for the following input:

```
redEdges=[[2,2],[0,1],[0,3],[0,0],[0,4],[2,1],[2,0],[1,4],[3,4]]
blueEdges=[[1,3],[0,0],[0,3],[4,2],[1,0]]
```

...my output is:

```
[0,1,4,1,1]
```

But the correct solution is:

```
[0,1,2,1,1]
```

...because there is a path from node 0 to node 2 like this:

```
   red      blue
0 -----> 4 -----> 2
```

I have no idea why my code doesn't give 2 as this path should be found via my DFS algorithm.

I thought that it might be something with the [0,0] edge, but it seems that it doesn't have an impact on a solution.

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code deletes the vertex it has visited, but doesn't restore it when backtracking. There is a possibility that there is another path from vertex 0 to the one you just deleted that still needs to be traversed and is a shorter path.

Here is example input that demonstrates the problem:

```
redEdges = [[0,1],[2,3],[0,3]]
blueEdges = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Your code will correctly create the following adjacency lists:

```
Red = {0: [1, 3], 2: [3]}
Blue = {1: [2], 3: [4]}
```

With `dfs` the path 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 will be visited and during this traversal all the keys in these dictionaries will be deleted. As the loop over the outgoing edges from 0 is still active, `dfs` will still follow the red edge from 0 to 3, but there it finds no blue edges as the key 3 is not there anymore. And so the algorithm doesn't see the shorter path from 0 to 4, which is 0, 3, 4.

Not your question, but BFS is more suitable for finding *shortest* paths. I would suggest you rework the algorithm and use BFS instead.

Just to have a complete answer, here is a spoiler solution using BFS:

> `class Solution:
>      def shortestAlternatingPaths(self, n, redEdges, blueEdges):
>          # Build a separate adjacency list for each color
>          adj = [[[] for _ in range(n)], [[] for _ in range(n)]]
>          for i, edges in enumerate((redEdges, blueEdges)):
>              for x, y in edges:
>                  if x or y:
>                      adj[i][x].append(y)
>          # Collect shortest distances for each color separately
>          res = [[0] + [-1] * (n-1), [0] + [-1] * (n-1)]
>          # Start BFS at node 0, traversing with either color
>          frontier = [(0, 0), (0, 1)]
>          distance = 1
>          while frontier:  # BFS loop
>              nextfrontier = []
>              for node, color in frontier:
>                  for neighbor in adj[color][node]:
>                      # If not yet visited with this color...
>                      if res[color][neighbor] == -1:
>                          res[color][neighbor] = distance
>                          nextfrontier.append((neighbor, 1-color))
>              frontier = nextfrontier
>              distance += 1
>
>          # Get the minimum distance per node from the two color alternatives
>          return [min(a, b) if min(a, b) > -1 else max(a, b)
>                  for a, b in zip(*res)]`